# How to automatically set form and datagridview width csv

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-7.0

I have a Powershell script that I've downloaded from the Internet, and modified for my purposes.  My purposes are to open a CSV, make changes, hit a save button and X out.

My problem is I have to manually set the width of each CSV (from the script).  I can manually adjust the form grow / shrink but not the DataGrid

I want

- The Form and DataGrid to automatically grow or shrink depending on how many columns on launch or manually.
- The Form and DataGrid to automatically grow or shrink when I do an AutoFit on a column
- I basically don't want a scrollbar if I can help it

I have looked at several documents regarding the .net classes / methods etc.. and have been able to suss out a great many things but this.  I'm certain I'm not asking the right questions.  Any advice on a resource or an example would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of what I mean when I open a csv with many columns [image]

Or few columns:
[image]

My code is here.

```
[reflection.assembly]::load("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::load("System.Drawing") | Out-Null


# This block of code is a file dialog open box
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    # This uses Environmental Directory Settings such as Desktop
    # InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

    # Here you can pick the default directory.  If you comment it out, 
    # then OpenFileDialog seems to go to the last directory you chose a file from
    InitialDirectory = "C:\temp\Ricoh"

    # Pick file extensions to chose from.  The first is default.
    Filter = 'Comma Separated Values (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*|SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'
}

# The actual dialog open box
$dialogOpen = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

# This returns the full path and filename
$pathFileName = $FileBrowser.FileName
# Write-Host $pathFileName 

# This returns the filename only
$fileName = $FileBrowser.SafeFileName
# Write-Host $fileName 

$OnLoadForm_UpdateGrid= {

    # This returns the filename minus extension.
    $baseName = Get-Item $pathFileName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
    # Write-Host $baseName

    $tmp = $FileBrowser.InitialDirectory + '\' + $baseName + '.tmp'
    Write-Host $tmp

    #Make a copy of the file so we can import it and leave the real file free for exporting to
    Copy-Item $pathFileName -Destination $tmp

    # Load the tempfile into memory so we can work
    $tmpFileName = Import-Csv $tmp

    #Remove the tempfile now
    Remove-Item $tmp

    #Select the datasource so we can prep for the dataGridView
    $dataGridView1.DataSource=[System.Collections.ArrayList]$tmpFileName

    $form.refresh()
}


# This button will save the file
$button1_OnClick= {    
    $dataGridView1.Rows |Select -Expand DataBoundItem | Export-Csv $pathFileName -NoType
}

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Form Text Goes Here"
$Form.TopMost = $true

$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = "centerscreen"

$dataGridView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
}

$sds_width = 900
$sds_height = 450

$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sds_width,$sds_height)

$dataGridView1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($sds_width - 25),($sds_height - 100))
$dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
$dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $true
$dataGridView1AllowUserToResizeColumns = $true
$dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()

$dataGridView1.Name = $baseName
$dataGridView1.DataMember = ""
$dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 5
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 5

$dataGridView1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView1)
$form.add_Load($OnLoadForm_UpdateGrid)

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "Save"
$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(5,($dataGridView1.height + 25))
$button.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point(125, 25)

$button.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right

$button.TabIndex ="1"
$button.add_Click($button1_OnClick)
$form.controls.add($button)

$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: It should be possible to do this as a Windows Form UI but I think long-term you'll find it easier to control and layout a UI using XAML and WPF instead. Frustration like this is what lead me to learn XAML.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Thanks.  I'll look into xaml and then linking powershell to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **can** make your UI autosize, but we need to remove the hardcoded `size` values and convert those to `.MinimumSize`.  You will probably also want to add `.MaximumSize` properties or someone could open a huge `.csv` file and get a super bad looking UI.

We also want to set the `.AutoScale` and `.AutoSize` properties to true so the overall changes would look like.

```
$form.MinimumSize= New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sds_width,$sds_height)
$form.AutoScale = $true
$form.AutoSize = $true
```

We also need to set the same properties on the `DataGridView` as well.

```
$dataGridView1.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($sds_width - 25),($sds_height - 100))
$dataGridView1.AutoScale...
```

I also ran into an error because I didn't have a `C:\temp\Ricoh` path so you might want to put some error handling there on `line 38` like

```
if (Test-Path C:\temp\Ricoh){
   Write-Host "Found C:\temp\Ricoh path"
}
else{
   New-item "C:\temp\Ricoh" -ItemType Directory 
}
```

Now, I didn't say it would look pretty especially if the user has weird scaling like me.

[image]

One thing you might want to do is set the [Column's Header Height property, like in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheightsizemode?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough analysis.  I put that hard coded directory in as a convenience for testing.  Also, this is just an FYI, https://imgur.com/VAAOSH0 (Autoscale doesn't appear to work with datagridview)
Other issues, you can expand now, but you can't shrink.  I'm reading more documentation, but you answered the question (there's just other, new problems now :-)
Thanks.